# How to change URLs in all comments to pull requests in our GitHub project

Tags: github, github-api

Our Jenkins server has moved to a different data center, and its DNS name has changed.
All links to previous builds and logs files, recorded in pull requests comments in our GitHub projects, have suddenly become stale.

Is there a way to automatically edit all PR comments, and replace the old DNS name by the new one in the links, to make these links valid again?

Answer (score 1):

For existing PR comment, the (assuming here) GitHub CLI does not seem to expose the feature of editing existing comment.

[`gh pr comment`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_comment) would only create new PR comments.

You might need to use the [GitHub API  Update a review comment for a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#update-a-review-comment-for-a-pull-request)

```
patch /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/comments/{comment_id}
```

Which supposed in your case to [list comments first](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-review-comments-in-a-repository).

---

For existing commit messages which would include Jenkins URLs, you would need to:

- clone locally repository
- rewrite the commit messages
- force push everything ([`git push --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror))

Make sure your collaborators re-clone the new history.

To change to commit messages, use [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md))

> ### [Updating commit/tag messages](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_updating_commit_tag_messages)
>
> If you want to modify commit or tag messages, you can do so with the same syntax as `--replace-text`, explained above.
>
> For example, with a file named `expressions.txt` containing
>
> ```
> foo==>bar
> ```
>
> then running
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --replace-message expressions.txt
> ```
>
> will replace `foo` in commit or `tag` messages with `bar`.

Comment: AFAICS Op is only asking about PR comments in Github, not Git commit messages.

Comment: @dunni Indeed. I have rewritten the answer accordingly, but I would keep the comment/tag message part, in case it is relevant for others.

Comment: @VonC Thanks, I'll try to write a script using the API you referred to.  In between, I had a look at the github CLI, but unfortunately if does not (yet?) have commands for listing or updating comments.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisLarvoire Exactly, though it can call any GitHub API you want, through `gh api`: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api